# Does StyleCop SA1623 Incorrectly Trigger When the Method has an Attribute?

Tags: c#, stylecop

I am triggering several instances of [SA1623: PropertySummaryDocumentationMustMatchAccessors](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1623.html) in my code where I have a property similar to this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the location to check for files.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string SourceDirectory { get; set; }
```

This is code used in a [MSBuild Custom Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx) Library and the Attribute in question is [Microsoft.Build.Framework.RequiredAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.framework.requiredattribute.aspx) if that has any meaning.

I am using [StyleCop 4.7.14.0](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) with no modifications to the default rules. A quick search of StackOverflow, Google, and the Project's Open Issue logs and documentation shows no mention of this quirk, am I doing something wrong is is this a bug?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the style cop rules case sensitive?  You have 'Gets or Sets' but the rule says it must be 'Gets or sets'

Comment: They are indeed, can't believe I missed that. Do you wish to answer the question so I can accept as an answer?

Comment: You can post your own answer and mark it.  Credit Erv and all will be well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Per Erv Walter's comment above the StyleCop rule is cAsE sEnSiTive and must be exactly as shown:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the location to check for files.
/// </summary>
```

Note the lower case on the sets

Answer (score 9):

I had a real headache with this type of error and it was not intuitive to know what they really meant:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     SA1623 : CSharp.Documentation : The property's documentation
>   summary text must begin with: Gets or sets a value indicating whether

I was getting that and when looking at my code I had it well written, I started my summary with " Get or sets ...", but still kept getting the error

After almost going nuts, I realized this was showing for 2 ***Boolean*** properties, and what they were telling me is that for ***Boolean properties I should actually write the whole sentence literally starting with "Gets or sets a value indicating whether..."*** and the whatever my property does.

For example:

> ```
> /// <summary> /// 
> /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the product is active. 
> /// </summary> 
> public boolean Active { get; set; }
> ```

I hope this saves time to others.

Comment: I just had this exact issue, and this answer was a savior. Thanks!

Comment: this worked for me. Already had "Gets or sets ... ", for my bool, but when changed to "Gets or sets a value indicating whether ..." it passed. I hate SC.

Comment: Had the same issue, also spelled whether wrong and the error wasn't going away.